# Scifi movie - Prisoners kept in high-tech work camps by aliens

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a (recent-ish) science fiction movie where people are placed in working camps. There's an electrical fence around the camp to avoid people from escaping. Groups of people try to destroy the fence with the material they have.

There are multiple camps all over the world and above the camp there is a big ship which they also try to destroy. There was this guy on a motorcycle crossing through the camp killing aliens.

I remember that they make some kind of suit to they use to climb the fence with.

At the beginning of the movie the person did something wrong and was moved to the camp because of that, I guess he stole something or attacked one of the aliens.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Much better. Very much better indeed. You have my +1 and a reopen vote

Comment: True that the description could fit several things, but it does not sound like a movie to me but instead the TV show Falling Skies, the last season if i recall.  This is pretty much an exact description of one of the episodes.

Comment: Man, thank you so much it was falling skies indeed. Great Tv Show, thought it was a movie. You are great have been searching for hours.

Comment: @Mykewlname, hurry and post that as an answer so that it can get Accepted.

Comment: You should also mark this as answered :)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in my comment, I believe you are referring to the TV show Falling Skies, the 4th season and not a SciFi movie.  In Season 4 during the first 4 episodes the story revolves around "The Ghost" who is really Tom Mason with the 2nd Mass resistance troops fighting the aliens and he along with others from his unit are imprisoned in an Espheni Ghetto camp.  Some of his men construct a Faraday suit to get over the force field and escape.

References can be found on the Falling Skies Wiki
http://fallingskies.wikia.com/wiki/Season_4